# Automating Instagram likes

Tags: python, selenium, automation, bots, instagram

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def login(usr,pss):

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
time.sleep(2)

usr_nm = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input')
usr_nm.clear()
usr_nm.send_keys(usr)
time.sleep(2)

pss_nm = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input')
pss_nm.clear()
pss_nm.send_keys(pss)
time.sleep(2)

login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]')
login.click()
time.sleep(2)

saveinfo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/div/section/div/button')
saveinfo.click()
time.sleep(2)

noti = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]')
noti.click()
time.sleep(2)





def like(hashtag):
    driver.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{hashtag}/")
    time.sleep(2)

    # for scroll down

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    href_found = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

    pic_href = [ele.get_attribute('href') for ele in href_found if '.com/p' in ele.get_attribute('href')]

    for ele in pic_href:
        driver.get(ele)
```

**After this the code is not working, I tried placing it in the loop but it stops working and throws an error that 'list doesn't have attribute click( )'**

```
like = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button/div/span')
like.click()
time.sleep(2)



login(<your username >,<your password>)

like('hacking')
```

Comment: `find_elements_by_xpath` .. keyword: elements (plural). That returns a list. A list cannot be clicked.

Comment: so what should I use to get each element and then get it to click, also I have improved some code already but still, the like feature is not triggered.

Comment: You used `find_element...` for everything else, what was wrong with that... Or have you tried access _specific items within the list_ to click?